# Find objects inside particular object in IFC file

Tags: autodesk-forge

There's a building inside an IFC file that has IFCSPACE rooms. Some of those rooms contain IFCSPACE objects (geometry and metadata) that define living, storage, sanitary and other areas.

Is there a way to get those IFCSPACE objects inside every room using Forge APIs?

The goal is to have this kind of statistics for every room:

Room A (50 m2) has:
- Living area: 35 m2
- Storage area: 5 m2
- Sanitary area: 8 m2
- Other area: 2 m2

Whole web application is built with Forge PHP Client. [Data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yjrhr.jpg)

Comment: hi, i am checking with engineer team of Forge and will get back to you soon.

Comment: @XiaodongLiang, thanks for your efforts

Comment: @XiaodongLiang any news?:)

Comment: sorry, not yet.. I am broadening to more audiences. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: no response yet, but more close to the colleagues/team who might know the answer. Sorry for letting you wait. With my experience, it might probably be some data that has not extracted by IFC extractor..After confirmation by engineer team, I can log a wish.

Comment: sorry, finally, I have to log the question in the internal tracking system with our engineer team: NW-53845. I will watch what will happen with the investigation.